# how to declare/use a getcomponent variable in Unity3D c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have tried many for few hours and am scratching my head on how to get this done.

I need to get a variable from a script and change it by +3

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

    public class SwordKillScript : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject moneyAmount;
    private Component MoneyText;

    void Awake () { 
        moneyAmount = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Money");
        MoneyText = moneyAmount.GetComponent<moneyText> ();
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D collisonInfo){
        Debug.Log ("Killed");
        if (collisonInfo.collider.tag != "Player") {
            MoneyText.money += 3;
            Destroy (collisonInfo.collider.gameObject);
        }
        transform.position = transform.position;
    }
}
```

That is the code for a sword, when it hits an object it destroys it then is supposed to add +3 to this script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class moneyText : MonoBehaviour {

    Text txt;
    public int money = 20;

    void Start () {
        txt = gameObject.GetComponent<Text>(); 
        txt.text= "$: " + money;
    }
}
```

any help is great, I hope that this question is easy to read and answer.

Please answer as simply as possible and give the reason why, I will end up doing this sort of thing many times over and would love to know.

Thankyou!

BTW: Expect errors, I need to know what I can do to make this work - Thanks again.

EDIT: Here is the code I am having more trouble with, i've fiddled with assigning everything from strings to getcomponent, HALP!

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class MoneyText : MonoBehaviour {

    public GUIText txt;
    public int money = 20;

    public void ModifyMoney () {
        money += 3;
        txt.text = "$: " + money;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong in your script. You're getting the component correctly, and also incrementing the value correctly. The reason you're probably not seeing the updated value is because you set the value of the text only once in the `Start()` function.

i.e. `txt.text= "$: " + money;`

There's many ways of updating the text. You could do any of the following

A) Make the `txt` variable in `moneyText` public. Then in your `SwordKillScript`, you can add the following line

`MoneyText.money += 3; //You have this already
moneyAmount.txt.text = "$: "+MoneyText.money;  //Add this line`

B) Write a method in the `moneyText` class which modifies the value of `money`.

```
public void ModifyMoney (int howMuch) {
    money += howMuch;
    txt.text = "$: "+money;
}
```

Call this method from `SwordKillScript`

C) You can make `money` a property.

```
private int money = 20;
public int Money {
    get { return money; }
    set { 
        money = value;
        txt.text = "$ : "+money;
    }
}
```

Then, in `SwordKillScript`, you just need to increment `Money`

P.S. Your naming conventions are a little off. Might I suggest that you take a look at it? Class names, for example, begin with an uppercase (MoneyText instead of moneyText)

Comment: Thanks, I'm glad it was just something small. Once again I am a newb so i will work on my naming conventions, thankyou!

Comment: UnassignedReferenceException: The variable txt of MoneyText has not been assigned.
You probably need to assign the txt variable of the MoneyText script in the inspector.
MoneyText.ModifyMoney () (at Assets/MoneyText.cs:16)
UnityEngine.GameObject:SendMessage(String)
SwordKillScript:OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D) (at Assets/SwordKillScript.cs:17)                                                                                             This is the error im getting if you need my code ill edit into my original post.